# I am struggling with dming members with a certain role in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here's the code

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.utils import get

@client.command()
async def play(ctx):
       red_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="Red")
       blue_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="Blue")

       red_boss_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name="Red Boss")
       blue_boss_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name="Blue Boss")
```

and then DMing

```
for i in red_boss_role_id.members:
    await i.send("" + str(red_agents))
for i in blue_boss_role_id.members:
    await i.send("" + str(blue_agents))
```

I have already tried same thing with IDs, but no progress
It says the error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'server'
```

Comment: Where are you sending the dm from in your code? Is that only just a small portion of it, or is that the whole of your code?

Comment: ok I've edited it, sorry it's my first question posted. It's only a part of code where errors occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is you are using `server`, as it is not defined, it is giving you an error `AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'server'` and it states it is not an attribute of message.

`red_role`  and `blue_role`  both were using `guild`, I've changed the ones below to guild, hopefully this works for you

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx):
       red_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="Red")
       blue_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="Blue")

       red_boss_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="Red Boss")
       blue_boss_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="Blue Boss")
```

Answer (score 1):

That error message already says everything. Your problem arises because you are trying to to access `ctx.message.server.roles` when the correct syntax would be `ctx.message.guild.roles`.

I suggest you use the following code, as yours is pretty redundant:

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx):
       red_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Red")
       blue_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Blue")

       red_boss_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Red Boss")
       blue_boss_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Blue Boss")
```